# How to get a migration config item in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

As usual, to access CodeIgniter's configuration item from a `$config` array, I would use this function `$this->config->item('some_item');`. That's fine, but how can I access a config items from this file `app/config/migration.php` ? where `$config['migration_enabled']` is located

I'm doing a `$this->config->item('migration_enabled')` or `$this->config->item('migration_version')`, but it returns me always `FALSE`, anyone know why ? And how can I work it out to make it accessible within the controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load the migration config before you access it. You can either load it on demand in your controller via:

`$this->config->load('migration');`

or you can autoload it in your `config/autoload.php` file by adding it to the `$autoload['config']` array:

`$autoload['config'] = array('migration');`